# On Non homogeneous linear recurrence relation and power series associated with it:

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

Consider the following Non homogeneous recurrence relation :

$$T(2n) = nc_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k T(2(n-k))$$

Now consider the following power series :

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T(2n) x^n$$

> > Question :  Other possible representation of $F(x)$ with explanation?

Comment: $F(x)=\dfrac{xC'(x)}{1-C(x)}$ where $C(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n x^n$.

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you for the answer , but is there a relatively elegant proof you can state ?