# Exponential generating function with recurrent coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations, power-series, generating-functions

Consider the following Non homogeneous recurrence relation :

$$T(2n) = nc_{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k T(2(n-k))$$

Now consider the following power series :

$$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ T(2n) x^n}{n!}$$

> > Question :  can we get a compact form for $F$?

Comment: Without some conditions on the $c_k$, probably not.

Comment: @Math1000 thank u for the comment ; What conditions c_k has to follow ? ( In my case  $ c_k=(c^{2k})/(2k+1)! $ ,Where c is a constant)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506806/on-non-homogeneous-linear-recurrence-relation-and-power-series-associated-with-i Why ask the same question twice?

Comment: @Math1000 this is not dupilcate . You can see this question has exponential generating function and the other contains ordinary generating function ( also I know how to convert OGF to EGF by integral transform but in my case it gets messy , so the different question )